# Nested object is not updated

Tags: javascript, gun

Create a nested node

```
var app = gun.get('app');
var node = app.get('watcher/1').put({"stats":{"num":3},"name":"trex"});
```

Listen to updates

```
app.get('watcher/' + id).get('stats').on(function (v, k) {
  console.log('v:', v); 
  console.log('k:', k);
});
```

Get the update on web page load (the devtools console output)

```
(index):62 v: {"_":{"#":"j9782ilz019k9aUsJJj5c8Q5O",">":{"num":1508946976437}},"num":3}
(index):63 k: stats
```

Update the node

```
app.get('watcher/1').put({"stats":{"num":4},"name":"trexxx"});
```

No updates in the console!

jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sergibondarenko/e6ctqaqL/69/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@trex this was a bug you found, and is now fixed in `v0.8.9`+.